# I keep getting 'Could not determine ADB version' in Android Studio. I am using a mac with the M1 chip

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP118.png]

This keeps popping up non-stop.

I have 0 ideas how to fix it. I am also new to the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with downgrade my adb.
You could download old version, https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r27.0.0-windows.zip is an example.